# QMenuBar is not displayed in form in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I can not understand what has caused this strange behavior of QMenuBar:

The **menu-bar is not displayed** when I declare in the header file (dialog.h):

```
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>
...
private:
    QMenuBar* bar;
    QMenu* file;
...
```

And in the source file in the constructor:

```
...
    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    bar = new QMenuBar(this);
    file = new QMenu("File");
    bar->addMenu(file);
    mainLayout->addWidget(bar);
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
...
```

If I create a menu-bar directly in the constructor (not declaring it in the header file), everything works and the menu-bar appears on the form:

```
...
    QMenuBar * b = new QMenuBar(this);
    QMenu * m = new QMenu("File1");
    b->addMenu(m);
    mainLayout->addWidget(b);
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
...
```

And **on Windows** I haven't got such problem. This behavior only **on Linux**.

What I am doing wrong? Is there anything that I misunderstand?

I have Qt 4.8.3 and gcc vesion 4.4.7 .

This is a form with correct behavior of Menu-bar:

[image: Form with correct behavior of Menu-bar]

Comment: What Linux? Are you sure that the menu isn't on the top of the screen and only when your application has focus (like on Ubuntu)?

Comment: @Ann Orlova, screenshot looks like you're using Ubuntu with Unity, so Zlatomir is right, it's just OS design confused you, menu bars there located on the top of the screen, not on the top of the application window

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Is there any way to make menu-bar to be displayed on application?

Comment: QAnn Orlova, I can't replicate your problem.  I'm using Mate, which hopefully has enough similarities.  I also think you have a layout problem.  Are you sure that all later widgets in your dialog are being added to your `QVBoxLayout mainLayout`?  If not, they may be showing up on top, hiding the menubar.  As for Unity, that's an overall window manager style.  If you want menubars to appear differently in general, you should use a different window manager (maybe getting off-topic here).

Comment: @Ann Orlova, you can google it, there should be solutions for that, but OS tweaking is definetly an offtopic on stackoverflow. We all want to know, is menu bar appearing (no matter on the top of application window or screen), or the problem is still valid and waiting for answer?

Comment: Yes, Mebu-bar is appearing on the top of the screen. I'm closing the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do not edit the question. Mark the answer as accepted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code I obtain:

```
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout
```

In facts, deleting the 2 lines

```
mainLayout->addWidget(bar);
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

I've got the menu (in facts in the application and in Unity top bar, too).

However, if it's the main menu in your window, don't create a QMenuBar, but use

```
menuBar()->addMenu(file);
```

`QMainWindow::menuBar ()` returns the menu bar for the main window. Moreover, this function creates and returns an empty menu bar if the menu bar does not exist.

Comment: You're assuming that Ann is basing her 'dialog' class on the `QMainWindow` class, which she hasn't specified.  If you run that on just a plain QWidget or QDialog, it should be fine.